# On Heroku Postgres, how to change full-text search dictionary?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, full-text-search, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

I'm wanting to change the `default_text_search_config` of my "Hobby Basic Heroku Postgres" database. After running

`heroku pg:psql` and
`\dF`,

I can see that Heroku has a preset stop dictionary that I want - Russian (`pg_catalog.russian`), so there is no need to create a new dictionary (although I see many questions about this as well).

According to the [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-configuration.html), one can change this by altering the `postgresql.conf`, which is not applicable in this case, or by setting it for an individual session. I've tried setting it through the CLI with

`SET default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.russian';`

However, as soon as I exit the CLI, it reverts to the initial `pg_catalog.english`.

I'm using Prisma, so I've tried applying a migration of this as well, thinking that the issue was the session not persisting after I closed the CLI. This also was not successful.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is also possible to [set the default at the database level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-INTRO-CONFIGURATIONS):

> If you are using the same text search configuration for the entire cluster you can use the value in `postgresql.conf`. To use different configurations throughout the cluster but the same configuration within any one database, use `ALTER DATABASE ... SET`. Otherwise, you can set `default_text_search_config` in each session.

Assuming your database is called `abcdefg`, try the following:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE abcdefg SET default_text_search_config TO 'pg_catalog.russian';
```

I suspect this will work on Heroku's offering, but have not tried it.